# Why did Zoso trick Rumplestilskin into killing him?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

After convincing Rumplestilskin to burn down the Duke's castle, steal the magic dagger, and keep the Dark One as his own slave, Zoso went on to insult Rumplestilskin to the point where he stabbed him in a blind rage.  Why did Zoso want Rumplestilskin to kill him?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Being the Dark One isn't pleasant and comes with side effects (look at Rumpelstiltskin before and after) and Zoso was tired of it.

> **Zoso:** Looks like you made a deal you didn’t understand. I don’t think
>   you’re going to do that again.
>
> **Rumpelstiltskin:** You told me to kill you.
>
> **Zoso:** My life was such a burden. You’ll see. Magic always comes with a
>   price and now, it’s yours to pay.